# Sequence points in a language with left to right evaluation order?

Tags: side-effects, sequence-points

When evaluation order is specified as "left to right" and language is a (pseudo) C-like, **which are the sequence points in the following examples?**

```
int x = 1;
int z = x-- + x; // z = 1 + 0 or z = 1 + 1?
my_func(x++); // x incremented before or after my_func execution?
my_func(x++ + --x); // combining those above
```

Comment: A "sequence point" in C has a precise definition. Does your "(pseudo) C-like" language define sequence points in the same way?

Comment: Those are excerpts from my exercises, the text states exactly what I wrote: "C-like language with dynamic scoping, shallow binding and expression evaluation from left to right". Nothing more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence point is what the language standard defines to be a sequence point. The answers I'm about to give apply to C, but another "C-like" language might very well define different sequence points and thus have different answers to those questions.

```
int z = x-- + x; // z = 1 + 0 or z = 1 + 1?
```

Since `+` is not a sequence point in C, the result of the above statement is undefined.

```
my_func(x++); // x incremented before or after my_func execution?
```

`x` is incremented before `my_func` runs, but `my_func` is called with the old value of `x` as an argument.

```
my_func(x++ + --x); // combining those above
```

Undefined for the same reason as the first one.

Comment: What about if z = ++x + y++? This statement shouldn't be undefined, right?

Comment: @Gremo: Yes, that's defined. Both `x` and `y` will be incremented by one and `z` will be the sum of the new value of `x` and the old value of `y`. That has nothing to do with sequence points though.

Comment: if x = 1; y = 2; z = 2 + 2; and then y = 3. Maybe I've misunderstood what a sequence point is?

Comment: @Gremo: Yes, `z` will be 4 and `x` and `y` will be 2 and 3 respectively. A sequence point is a point where everything before it is executed before anything after it. For example if `+` were a sequence point and you did `f(x) + g(x)`, you'd know that `f(x)` is executed first and `g(x)` second. However it is not, so you don't know which one will get executed first. So when you do something like `++x + (x+1)`, you don't know whether `++x` is executed before or after `x+1`, so the result is undefined.

Comment: what happens if my_func takes a reference, i.e. its signature is myfunc(int& x)? Is it then guaranteed to get the reference to the updated x? Or does it get the old version, but the old version is updated later? Or does it merely get a copy of the old version which doesn't live further than the function scope?